# Residual sum of squares of block matrix with sparse elements

Tags: regression, covariance, residuals, matrix, cholesky-decomposition

Based on the question [Residual Sum of squares in Weighted regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/234101/edit), a fast way to solve for 
$$(\mathbf{y-X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}})^{'}\mathbf{C}^{-1}(\mathbf{y-X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}})$$
is to transform the probelm to a regular linear regression through the following procedure

1) The cholesky decomposition of $\mathbf{C}$ is $\mathbf{C=RR^{'}}$ and $\mathbf{C^{-1}=R^{'-1}R^{-1}}$

2) The estiamtor of ${\boldsymbol\beta}$ can be written as : $$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}=(\mathbf{X^{'}C^{-1}X})^{-1}\mathbf{X^{'}C^{-1}y}=(\mathbf{X^{'}R^{'-1}R^{-1}X})^{-1}\mathbf{X^{'}R^{'-1}R^{-1}y}$$

3) Solving $\mathbf{R^{-1}X=A}$ and $\mathbf{R^{-1}y=B}$ with backsolve we get $$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}=(\mathbf{A^{'}A})^{-1}\mathbf{A^{'}B}$$ which is equivalent to the residual sum of squares (RSS) of unweighted regression.

In $3)$ the backsolve operator is really faster than inverting a matrix and solving for the unweighted regression estimator $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}$ can be done really fast using the $lm$ function

My question is related to the case when $\mathbf{C}$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix of the form

$$\pmatrix{A & 0 & 0 & E \\ 0 & B & 0 & F \\ 0 & 0 & C & G \\ E^\prime & F^\prime & G^\prime & D}$$

where matrices $A,B,C,D,$ are positive definite symmetric matrices.
Invering this matrix can be done using the schurr complement as in the question 
[Inverse of block covariance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214250/inverse-of-block-covariance-matrix).
However using the schur complement to find $\mathbf{C^{-1}}$ and then solving for  $(\mathbf{y-X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}})^{'}\mathbf{C}^{-1}(\mathbf{y-X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}})$ where $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}=(\mathbf{X^{'}C^{-1}X})^{-1}\mathbf{X^{'}C^{-1}y}$ seems far less efficient then the cholesky decomposition procedure.

Is there a way to further simplify the cholesky decomposition procedure when finding the RSS given that the matrix $\mathbf{C}$ is of the form above ? For instance is there an efficient way to calculate the cholesky decomposition of the sparse matrix $\mathbf{C}$ ?

Comment: The row reduction I described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201174/919 will make short work of this.  It reduces the question to inverting $A,B,C,$ and one other matrix of the dimensions of $D$.

Comment: @whuber a a row block operation does not change the determinant of the result, however is the inverse also maintained ? can you please eleborate how the inverse could be found based on your result through gaussian elimination ?

Comment: Row reduction is *the* standard way to solve systems of equations.  You just augment the matrix with the right hand side (namely, $y-X\hat\beta$) and row-reduce the augmented matrix.

Comment: @whuber Can you please elaborate how this can be done mathmatically ? Thank you

Comment: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination for an introduction or refer to your favorite linear algebra textbook.

Comment: In my experience, things like the Schur decomposition are used in two situations: 1) When the system is an update of a previously-solved related system, and 2) For illustrative purposes in derivations. In nearly all *practical* situations, matrices are not literally inverted (due to numerical concerns). I am not sure about other platforms, but in Matlab if you specified your matrix system, the `\` command would automatically take things like sparsity and positive definiteness into account, in order to determine the best way to solve the system (most likely sparse Cholesky, in this case).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 do you know if in R this same sparsity is automatically considered when using chol() ? or a specific function for cholesky decomposition of sparse matrices should be used ?

Comment: @raK1 to clarify: In Matlab sparse and dense matrices are different data types. Matlab does not check sparsity itself, but uses different algorithms based on the data type of the matrix. In R I do not know. Another point is that for *large* sparse matrices (as in physics simulators), direct solvers may be infeasible, and iterative solvers must be used (see also [here](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/81/what-guidelines-should-i-follow-when-choosing-a-sparse-linear-system-solver)). For example a Cholesky factor will have more nonzeros than the original matrix, due to "infill".

Comment: This structure looks like a (block) "arrow structure" or "block diagonal bordered" structure for which dedicated Cholesky decomposition algorithms exist. Google may first help, then a look into the documentation of CRAN R packages for sparse matrices.

Comment: @Yves there is no direct function for such matrices in R matrix package . Can teh cholesky decomposition of this arrow head matrix be expressed in a closed form function ?

Comment: Although 'Matrix' is the main one, there are several R packages on CRAN dedicated to  sparse matrices, e.g. spam. Yet it may be possible with some work to find a closed form expression since the structure of L in C = L L^t is known.

Comment: @Yves do you mean that the structure for L when C is an arrowhead matrix ? Do you have any reference for that ?

Comment: Yes, L is arrowhead. No reference, but simply write it with the same structure as the lower part of C (say with U', V', W' and H as the lowest block line), then solve for U, V, W and H will come. Of course the diagonal blocks in L are say L_A, L_B, and L_C, the Cholesky roots of A, B and C.

Answer (score 3):

The arrowhead and block arrowhead structures are preserved in 
Cholesky decomposition. So we can find the lower triangular Cholesky root 
$\mathbf{L}$ of the large sparse matrix $\mathbf{C}_0 = \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}'$ under  the form
$$
\mathbf{L} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
  \mathbf{L}_A &  &  &  \\
  &  \mathbf{L}_B &  &    \\
   & &  \mathbf{L}_C   &  \\
  \mathbf{U}' & \mathbf{V}' & \mathbf{W}' & \mathbf{H} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the blocks not shown are zeros.
Obviously $\mathbf{L}_A$, $\mathbf{L}_B$ and $\mathbf{L}_C$ are the Cholesky roots
of the diagonal blocks $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$. By identifying the first three 
elements of the last block line we get
$$
   \mathbf{U}'\mathbf{L}_A' = \mathbf{E}', \quad \mathbf{V}'\mathbf{L}_B' = \mathbf{F}', 
   \quad \mathbf{W}'\mathbf{L}_C' = \mathbf{G}'
$$
which gives the matrices $\mathbf{U}$,  $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{W}$, for instance
$\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{L}_A^{-1}\mathbf{E}$ would be obtained by `forwardsolve(LA, E)` in R.
Then identifying the fourth block element of the last block row gives
$$
\mathbf{U}'\mathbf{U} + \mathbf{V}'\mathbf{V} + \mathbf{W}'\mathbf{W} + 
\mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}' = \mathbf{D}. 
$$
So $\mathbf{H}$ can be the transpose of the Cholesky root $\mathbf{L}_S$ of the matrix
$$
  \mathbf{S} := \mathbf{D} - \mathbf{U}'\mathbf{U} - \mathbf{V}'\mathbf{V} - \mathbf{W}'\mathbf{W}.
$$
To summarise, in R the computation of $\mathbf{L}$ would take the form of three `forwardsolve` to find
$\mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{W}$, three `crossprod` and a subtraction to
form  $\mathbf{S}$, then a `chol`. Of course if you only want to solve a linear system
it is not necessary to form the large Cholesky root, but rather to solve systems
using `forwardsolve` on block sub-vectors.

A problem may arise when the conditioning of the large matrix $\mathbf{C}_0$ is not good enough. It
could be the case then that the matrix $\mathbf{S}$ would not be numerically positive 
definite.

```
## Change this for more tests 'n' is the size of diagonal blocks
set.seed(314159)
n <- c("A" = 2, "B" = 2, "C" = 2, "D" = 3)

## origin and end of the blocks
nB <- length(n); n0 <- sum(n)
to <- cumsum(n)
from <- 1 + c(0, to[1:(nB-1)])
names(from) <- names(n)

## build a block-triangular (but not triangular) 'R' root of 'C0' with
## the wanted structure, then get 'C0' which will be symmetric and
## positive definite by construction, and also will have the wanted
## structure.

R <- array(0, dim = c(n0, n0))

for (i in 1:nB) {
    Ri <- array(runif(n[i] * n[i]), dim = c(n[i], n[i]))
    ind <- from[i]:to[i]
    R[ind, ind] <- Ri
}

## 'indLast' contains the indices of the last block

indLast <- ind
R[indLast, 1:to[nB - 1]] <- runif(n[nB] * to[nB - 1])

## get 'C0'

C0 <- R %*% t(R)

## now retrieve the Cholesky root 'L0' of 'C0' as suggested (could be
## done with a sparse matrix as well)
## o 'C0[ind, indLast]' will succesively be 'E', 'F' and 'G'
## o The matrix 'Lind' will successively contain 'L_A', 'L_B', 'L_C'
## o The matrix 'Mind' will successively contain 'E', 'F', 'G' which
##   could better have been named say 'M_1', 'M_2', 'M_3' ...

D <- C0[indLast, indLast]
L0 <- array(0, dim = c(n0, n0))

for (i in 1:(nB-1)) {
    ind <- from[i]:to[i]
    Lind <- t(chol(C0[ind, ind]))
    Mind <- forwardsolve(Lind, C0[ind, indLast])
    D <- D - crossprod(Mind, Mind)
    L0[ind, ind] <- Lind
    L0[indLast, ind] <- t(Mind)
}
L0[indLast, indLast] <- t(chol(D))

## finally compare with the "true" value"

L0.true <- t(chol(C0))
max(abs(L0 - L0.true))
```